# Draw multiple rectangles in an image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to locate rectangles in an image, and apply a classifier to recognize numbers inside each one, using a previously trained classifier:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

features = x_train[:8000, :, :]
labels = y_train[:8000]
list_hog_fd = []

for feature in features:
    fd = hog(feature.reshape((28, 28)), orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
    list_hog_fd.append(fd)
hog_features = np.array(list_hog_fd, 'float64')


clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(hog_features, labels)

imPath = "/Users/alessandro/Downloads/prova prova(2).jpg"
im = cv2.imread(imPath)

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours in the image
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get rectangles contains each contour
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]
```

From this point onwards it works perfectly, with my own image, but whenever I start the for loop, it generates empty "roi"s, returning the error "error:

**OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'"**

At line "roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)".

```
# For each rectangular region, calculate HOG features and predict
# the digit using Linear SVM.
for rect in rects:

    # Draw the rectangles
    cv2.rectangle(im, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3) 

    # Make the rectangular region around the digit
    leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
    pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
    pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
    roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]

    # Resize the image
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))

    #Calculate the HOG features
    roi_hog_fd = hog(roi, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
    nbr = clf.predict(np.array([roi_hog_fd], 'float64'))
    cv2.putText(im, str(int(nbr[0])), (rect[0], rect[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow("Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs", im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

How can I fix the code?

P.s. For reference, check http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/24/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-opencv-sklearn-and-python.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you copy code.

**Steps to solution**

1) If you copy code, try to understand what is happening

2) Realize that copying code is not magical. It simply doesnt have to work everywhere

3) If there is error, google the error and try to find out why the error happens

4) If you copy code from tutorial and it doesnt work, dont ask at StackOverflow

5) Your problem is on the lines

```
# Make the rectangular region around the digit
leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]
```

Make sure

```
roi
```

has image dimensions and that it has any pixels in it. You can test it by simply printing the shape like this

```
print(im_th.shape)
# Make the rectangular region around the digit
leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]
print(roi.shape)
```

You will see what is happening

Comment: I am indeed loading an image, and the path refers to the image that is currently on my disk. @Martin

Comment: In that case, your image is damaged on the way. show us the line on which the error occurs

Comment: It is raised at "roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)" but it's due to the previous lines.

Comment: I smell that on the lines : # Make the rectangular region around the digit #,  you damage the image. Print these values pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng and see what is happening. I think you crop the image in such way, that you lose your matrix

Comment: The point is that roi has shape (350, 0), while im_th (571, 926)

Comment: I tried with another image, not cropped, and it works; can't currently figure out why it didn't work but probably the rectangles couldn't be recognize in the smaller image; hence, the shape (350,0). Thank you for your help

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli The algorithm from the tutorial sucks. I am not good at reading someone else code, but problem is in extraction pt1,pt2 or leng. I am pretty sure, that if you put there condition, you will be fine for all images. Like if 0 not in roi.shape: pass

Comment: But I belive rectangles are recognized, otherwise you wouldnt even get inside the loop

Comment: Thank you for the hints @Martin